# ¿Cómo se agrupan los valores de las celdas de un marco de datos en un índice de una dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Para un modelo de `machine learning` quiero transforma un `dataframe` que esta como el siguiente:

```
   print (df)
       theme  A         B           C
    0  theme1 truc.pdf  truc.pdf    machin.pdf
    1  theme2 truc.xls  ohlala.csv  bidule.pdf
```

Para el siguiente:

```
print (df)
   fichier    theme  Pays
0  truc.pdf   theme1 [A,B]
1  machin.pdf theme1 [C]
2  ohlala.csv theme2 [B]
3  bidule.pdf theme2 [C]
```

Aqui lo que hé intentado, pero falta:

```
import pandas as pd

# Ejemplo de dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Theme': ['Theme1', 'Theme2', 'Theme3'],
                   'colonne2': ['document.docx', 'fichier.txt', 'code.py'],
                   'colonne3': ['image.png', 'fichier.txt', 'texte']})

# definir la función para encontrar las ocurrencias del nombre de archivo
def find_filename(column):
    filenames = []
    for cell in column:
        if isinstance(cell, str) and '.' in cell:
            filenames.append(cell)
    return filenames

# aplicar la función a cada elemento del marco de datos
filename_occurrences = df.applymap(find_filename)

# crear un nuevo marco de datos que contenga el nombre de los archivos y su ubicación
filename_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Nom du fichier', 'Emplacement'])

for col in filename_occurrences:
    for row in range(len(filename_occurrences.index)):
        for filename in filename_occurrences[col][row]:
            filename_df = filename_df.append({'Nom du fichier': filename, 'Emplacement': col}, ignore_index=True)

# afficher la nouvelle dataframe
print(filename_df)
```

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [ask]. Parte importante de la cultura del sitio es que al publicar una pregunta se muestre un esfuerzo por parte del autor al incluir el código que ha intentado o lo que ha investigado ya que en este sitio no hacemos tareas/proyectos. Lectura recomendada: ¿Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Me sorprende que no es tu primera pregunta y sin embargo en muchas no incluyes información relevante y/o lo que se ha intentado o investigado. Por favor agrega la información faltante.

Comment: Buen día, he publicado una respuesta y la he ocultado, cuando muestres lo que has intentado la hago visible. Saludos!

Comment: Eso es, @HeytalePazguato ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Puedes utilizar [`pandas.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) en combinación con `groupby` para hacerlo.

Ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd

# Crear el dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'theme': ['theme1', 'theme2'],
    'A': ['truc.pdf', 'truc.xls'],
    'B': ['truc.pdf', 'ohlala.csv'],
    'C': ['machin.pdf', 'bidule.pdf']
})

# Utilizar melt para generar la relación entre theme, Pays y fichier
df_melted = df.melt(id_vars='theme', var_name='Pays', value_name='fichier')

# Agrupar utilizando fichier y theme
# Crear una lista de Pays
df_transformed = df_melted.groupby(['fichier', 'theme']).agg({'Pays': list}).sort_values(by=['theme'])

# Crear una nueva columna temporal con el tamaño de la lista en Pays
df_transformed['len'] = df_transformed['Pays'].str.len()

# Ordenar por len de forma descendente y borrar la columna temporal
df_transformed = df_transformed.sort_values(by=['len'], ascending = False).drop(columns='len').reset_index()

print(df_transformed)
```

Esto imprime el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
      fichier   theme    Pays
0    truc.pdf  theme1  [A, B]
1  machin.pdf  theme1     [C]
2  bidule.pdf  theme2     [C]
3  ohlala.csv  theme2     [B]
4    truc.xls  theme2     [A]
```